# How do I integrate a changing index in a variable name?

Tags: python, loops, variables, indexing

I'm new to python. I am trying to run a script that runs a program(simulation) multiple times with different inputs. For each loop, I would like to get the duration of the runtime. Since there are multiple runs, I would like to get a duration1, duration2, duration3.... durationi, so I can check at the end how long each runtime took.
How can I integrate the continous index "i" into the variable name?

```
i=1
while i <= ......:
   start_time = time.time()
   return_code = subprocess.call(""runtheprogramm"")
   print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
   duration = ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
   i +=1
```

variable "i" should be integrated in duration+i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother creating discrete variables; it's messy and there's no benefit. Best way is to create a list and add the duration value to it on each iteration. So, your code becomes:

```
durations = []
i=1
while i <= ......:
   start_time = time.time()
   return_code = subprocess.call(""runtheprogramm"")
   print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
   duration = ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
   durations.append(duration)
   i += 1
print(durations)
```

The only caveat is that, as shown, the indices of the entries in the durations list will run from 0...n-1 whereas i goes from 1 to n. You could initialise durations with a dummy value for index zero.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for :)